# Distribute PyInstaller exe in Setup package

Tags: python

I have successfully creating an exe that runs everywhere using PyInstaller, however I want to distribute the exe by asking user to install it using setup.exe. I have little knowledge about creating setup file. Usually setup file allows selecting destination directory for where the exe will reside, and also comes with uninstaller in case user does not want the software anymore.

My case is

- My app is App.exe + some XMLs (configurable files by user) in a folder where the exe is. It is running well except it need to be packaged
- My App.exe lacks installer (Setup.exe) which will extract the app.exe + Xmls to the directory user select and uninstaller (Repair/Uninstall) feature which remove the app.exe + default xmls (or user created/modified version)

My question is, in such case how do I create such setup.exe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shameless self-promotion, but I made a video that deals exactly with that problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KRMs9z6KoEU

Essentially, you would need to download an application that will be a "setup builder". The tool I use in my video is called InnoSetup - it's free, and very simple to use. It also has a wizard that allows you to add additional files during setup (such as the XMLs you mentioned, or a help file for example). It can be done through a wizard, or added manually (InnoSetup uses its own version of Pascal - you'll see it when you try it!)

Comment: Wow, that helps a lot, exactly my need. Watching the video now